# How to hide the keyboard of a UITextView without resign first responder?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I have a `UITextView` wrapped in a `UIViewRepresentable`.

What I'm trying to do now is display a sheet instead of the keyboard to format the selected text, just like the iOS Notes app.

[image: Notes app]

So far I can display the sheet, but I can't keep the `UITextView` editable and dismiss the keyboard at the same time.

I've tried replacing `textView.inputView` in my delegate class, but looks like it only works if I do it inside `makeUIView`.

Is there's a way to do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
struct EditorView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var model: EditorModel
    
    let textView = UITextView()
    
    init(model: EditorModel) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        textView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        textView.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textView.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        let boldButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Format text",
            image: UIImage(systemName: "textformat"),
            primaryAction: UIAction(title: "Format text", handler: { UIAction in
                model.isTextFormatSheetVisible = true
                textView.inputView = UIView() // This doesn't work
            })
        )
        toolBar.setItems([boldButton], animated: true)

        textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        textView.attributedText = model.attributedText
        textView.selectedRange = model.selectedRange
        
        if (model.isTextFormatSheetVisible) {
            textView.inputView = UIView()
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        private var parent: EditorView
        
        init(_ parent: EditorView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.model.attributedText = textView.attributedText
            parent.model.selectedRange = textView.selectedRange
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.model.selectedRange = textView.selectedRange
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [reloadinputviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621110-reloadinputviews) should make the input view change take effect when the text view is already the first responder, which is the case with the selection change delegate method.

Comment: Thank you! It works, it took me ages to find a solution to this.